# How to force svelte component to mount in an {#if} block

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component, svelte-store

I have a sidebar with collapsible sections that use slots like this:

```
<Sidebar> // creates writable context
   <Searchbar /> // updates context

   <Collapsible>
      <MyControl label="hello" /> // subscribes to context to check if label matches search
      <MyControl label="world" /> // subscribes to context to check if label matches search
   </Collapsible>
</Sidebar>
```

`Sidebar` creates a writable context which `Searchbar` updates and `MyControl` subscribes to in order to check if it's being searched. My issue is because my controls are in an `{#if}` block, they don't mount until `Collapsible` is expanded just 1 time first, and if they don't mount then they never subscribe to the context and my search doesn't work. As soon as the Collapsible section is expanded just 1 time (can be collapsed afterwards) my searchbar works.

Collapsible.svelte:

```
{#if expanded}
  <div transition:slide>
     <slot />
  </div>
{/if}
```

My question is basically can i force my `<slot />` to mount? or is there some other way to solve this issue?

Comment: Reading your question carefully, it can be answered with "You can force your slot to mount by not putting it in an `#if`" because you didn't add any qualifying need.  I'm going to guess you want it mounted but not visible, so I'd wrap it in a something with a `display: none` css property controlled by `expanded` instead of the `#if`

Comment: yeah that is an option, i just edited my question my `<slot />` is wrapped in a div that has the `transition:slide` property. as far as i know that only works with conditional rendering and i was trying to avoid using css for this since svelte has nicely built-in animations so i was curious if there was another way @possum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved it myself using a #key block and the in/out transitions like this:

```
{#key expanded}
    <div 
          class={clsx(!expanded && "hidden")}
          in:getAnimation={{fn: slide, cond: expanded}} 
          out:getAnimation={{fn: slide, cond: !expanded}}>
         <slot />
    </div>
{/key}
```

where `getAnimation` is:

```
 const getInAnimation = (node, options) => {
   if (options.cond) {
     return options.fn(node, options);
   }
 };
```